# Eclipse quick fix dialogue hides bottom line

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

Whenever the Eclipse quick fix dialogue pops up, all options are visible, but as soon as the mouse is moved to the dialogue the bottom option is hidden by a button saying "Configure Annotation Preferences". To see the bottom option again I will need to scroll down in the dialogue. This happens even if there is only one option in the pop up.

I find this very annoying, since I'm more likely to select a quick fix option than to change some preferences. (Am I the only one?:))

How can I get rid of the button, or at least get the dialogue to resize itself so no options are hidden?

I'm runnig Juno on Ubuntu_64, v12.04.

Comment: I would also like to know this. I was going to submit a bug report to Eclipse but I think it would be a drop in the ocean...

Comment: For what it's worth, pressing Ctrl-1 gives me a popup that's looks ok, so I'm using that until this gets fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the preference *Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editor -> Text Editors -> When mouse moved into hover* to "Enrich on click" to work around the issue. Works fine for me on the same Ubuntu setup.

Be warned that this only works for hovers which don't need to be scrolled. If scrolling is necessary to see the content at the bottom, then either clicking into the popup or scrolling with the mouse wheel will still bring up that configuration button. To make this less of a problem, you may want to configure your Java, Lint or other plugins contributing quick fixes to ignore certain types of problems (which you never fix).

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks.

I still think the behaviour explained in the question is a bug, because with "Enrich on click" as you suggested, the button will not cover the bottom option. So there are clearly different behaviours for "Enrich on hover" and "Enrich on click".

Comment: With "Enrich on click" the button still covers up the bottom option for me (after you click).

Comment: @Timmmm, yes, same for us. I also wrote that in the answer. Scrolling will also cause the button to come up.